# WinForms html textBox

Tags: c#, components

I am looking for a simple textBox with Html capabilities like https://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/
I want to use it in a desktop program. 
I have searched a bit but I find rather old components. I would like a free one if it is possible and not a whole suite like devexpress.

Thanks

Comment: Wpf or Windows Forms? Do you mean for "html capabilites" that you want to save/load html files or you just need be able to edit a fancy document and don't metter the output file type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the "HtmlTextbox for Windows.Forms" control a while back for a very small portion of an application. It served it's purpose perfectly for what I needed to accomplish. It's open source on CodePlex. It hasn't been updated since 2012, but then again not much has changed with WinForms since the release of WPF. Give it a try, hopefully it works for you.

https://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for the link and giving a give-a-try solution... It helped me a lot!